# how to implement a custom partition on ApacheDS 1.5.5?

Tags: java, security, ldap, apacheds

I'm implementing a custom partition on Apache DS (implementing org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.Partition).

I´m able to do searches on my custom partition, however if I want to use a filter (i.e. objectClass=”person”) my partition returns all the entries found, with no filtering at all.

Can anyone give an example of how to filter the entries returned by the "search" method using a custom partition?

Also, it would be highly appreciated if someone can point me to complete examples of implementing the search method. I need more information, specially regarding Search Scopes (OBJECT, ONELEVEL or SUBTREE).

I'm using version 1.5.5 of ApacheDS.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working some time ago but had no time to post the solution.

Based on the example of this page: [How to write a simple custom partition for apache ds.](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/1.5/61-how-to-write-a-simple-custom-partition-for-apacheds.html)

I was able to build the initial partition. This however was not useful to my case. It would be great if ApacheDS had a nicer documentation.

So for filtering, I got an email from the Apache Developers List basically explaining that there are no classes to help you at all, you must do it your self (please correct me if I'm wrong since I'm interested on improving my code soon).

For example, you got the filter (objectClass=person) then you should do something like this:

```
if(ctx.getFilter().toString().contains("objectClass=person")) {
  //Somehow return entries that only correspond to persons on the data base (were you store your directory entries).
}
```

Actually, notice that the code example from above won't work, since ApacheDS translates the attribute names to their corresponding OID. So, instead of "objectClass" we would get 2.5.6, which is the OID for "objectClass" attribute.

Now regarding search scopes, the answer from JPBlanc says pretty much about it so I'm not repeating what he said. On your custom partition you will need to write your code to handle the tree cases differently.

For example:

```
switch (ctx.getScope()) {

  case OBJECT:
    //Find a particular entry on your entry database.
  case ONELEVEL:
    //Find all entries that match directly below a given entry.
  case SUBTREE:
    //Find all entries that match recursively below a given entry.
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

A Directory is a tree. When you search (write a SEARCH Protocol Data Unit) with LDAP in a Directory you give :

1. The DN of the nod where begin the search
2. The attributes you want to retreive
3. The filter ((&(objectClass=*))
4. The deepness of your search

For the deepness you've got 3 possibilities

- Subtree : try to match the filter in a recursive search from the begining nod.
- OneLevel : try to match the filter only in the nods under the begining nod.
- base : try to match the filter with the nod attributes (used to get RootDSE attributes).

If I come back to your problem. Be careful to the fact that there are implementation of type defined in the SCHEMA. Types are all derived from the type `top`. If I take as an example the type `inetOrgPerson` you can see in the SCHEMA that this type is a child of `organizationalPerson`, which is a chil of `person`, which is a chil of `top`. In this particular case an `inetOrgPerson` object will have his `objectClass` attribute valued 4 times :

```
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
```

So if you write a search PDU with a filter like (&(objectClass=person)) you will have objects issued from `person`, `organizationalPerson` and `inetOrPerson` types in your result.

Another thing in some search tools if the filter is bad written or not understood the default filter ((&(objectClass=*)) is used (this means everything).